# Parse nearGeoPoint not returning any objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8

Hi my query is very simple.
I basically want to return the objects ordered by the distance from the user.

If I pass in a PFGeoPoint, the query will return nothing. There are no errors.
If I don't put in a PFGeoPoint the query returns objects.

Whats going on?
Thanks :)

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "resorts")
    query.whereKey("geoPoint", nearGeoPoint: loc)
    query.limit = 100
    query.whereKey("showMe", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            self.objects = objects as [PFObject]
        }
     } //returns nothing



        var query = PFQuery(className: "resorts")
        query.whereKey("geoPoint", nearGeoPoint: loc)
        query.limit = 100
        query.whereKey("showMe", equalTo: true)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                self.objects = objects as [PFObject]
            }
         } //returns objects
```

Comment: Try query.orderByAscending("geoPoint"), rather than query.whereKey("geoPoint", nearGeoPoint: loc)

Comment: What would that do? That would just order it somehow but not based on the users location

Comment: Yes very true - I don't know what I was thinking... I'm not sure how nearGeoPoint works internally, if it has a maximum distance. Perhaps you could try to use the "withinKilometers" version of the method and set the kilometers to a really high value. Do you get anything then?

Comment: I could sort it myself but I'm lazy

Comment: Did you try setting explicit maximum distance?

Comment: No but I don't want one. I guess I could try something insane

Comment: It's to test if there's an implicit maximum distance

Comment: Oh good point I tried looking that yo yesterday, but to no avail. I'll test in a bit

Comment: Nope still doesn't work

Comment: Wait this actually fixed it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myList = [AnyObject]()

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(object:[AnyObject]!, error = NSError! ) -> Void in 

if error == nil {
            println("successful query")

            for object in objects {

                    self.myList.append(object)
                }
        } else {

        println(error)

        }


}
```